# Why INDIRECT function returns a 1?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to return a count of names from another sheet (it's a list of names in Column A and I want to pull the # of individual names into a cell in another sheet). I have many sheets with varying lists of names. I'm using the `COUNTA(INDIRECT` function, but I keep getting "1" as the result.

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!A:A))")
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Take a look here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there, just have to move the last quote inside the brackets and remove the extra bracket.

```
=COUNTA(INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!A:A"))
```

Answer (score 0):

to account for errors such as "nothing to count" you will need:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(INDIRECT("'"&A2&"'!A:A")))
```

and btw that was the reason why you were getting **`1`** from your formula attempt because `COUNTA` counted the error.